# Dúvida em função recursiva

Tags: c, recursão

Quando coloco:

```
return n * fatqua(n-1)
```

o programa retorna o resultado esperado que é `24`.

Porém quando coloco:

```
return n * fatqua(--1)
```

o resultado do programa é `0`. Não estou conseguindo entender a lógica dessa operação.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fatqua(int n){

    printf("\n numero : %d",n);
    system("Pause");
    if(n>0)
    {
        return n * fatqua(n-1) ;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    int n, resul=0;

    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    resul= fatqua(n);
    printf("\n\n Fatorial e igual a: %d",resul);

}
```

Comment: `--1` não faz sentido, pra que fazer isso?

Comment: @bigown eu acho que ele quis dizer `--n`

Comment: Se você quer dizer `--n`, isso ocorre porque o decremento de `n` vai acontecer antes da multiplicação. Portanto quando `n` for `1` você vai multiplicar o resultado final por `0`.

Comment: @bfavaretto tu respondeu 2s antes de mim :|

Comment: @Genos Se quiser postar uma resposta mais detalhada abaixo, fique à vontade ;). Eu parei por aqui.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu vou esperar o dono da pergunta responder se é `--n`. Se for eu posto. Valeu!

Comment: Eu não respondi porque não sei o que ele quer ainda.

Comment: --1 é igual a 1, não?

Comment: @Sorack ??????? é erro de sintaxe. E se não fosse, faria mais sentido que desse zero, não?

Comment: Não sei te dizer, --1 em javascript da erro, mas em C não tenho nem idéia

Comment: Nós entendemos perfeitamente o fatorial, mas uma dica é sempre indicar a entrada que gerou a saída informada. Neste caso, sabemos que 24 é 4!

Comment: era --n mesmo, vlw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Assumindo que você queria o parâmetro `--1`:

Isso gera um erro de compilação:

```
fat2.c:10:27: error: lvalue required as decrement operand
         return n * fatqua(--1) ;
```

Apenas para deixar claro, `lvalue` é o mesmo que *locator value*. Isto quer dizer que a função espera receber um valor endereçável, e não uma constante.

## Assumindo que você queria o parâmetro `--n`:

Bom, aqui temos algo interessante e a sua pergunta já foi feita no stackoverflow. Temos [neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405031/decrement-operator-in-c) e [neste outro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104870/recursion-in-c-with-pre-increment) algumas respostas úteis.

Ressalto aqui alguns pontos importantes:

- Usar `--n` causará o decremento antes que a instrução seja executada. Devido ao pré-decremento, a expressão avaliada será `(n-1) * fatqua(n-1)`;
- A multiplicação é comutativa (A * B = B * A), e isto a torna perigosa na hora de avaliar esta expressão. A ordem de avaliação dos argumentos é indefinida neste caso. Por isso é uma boa prática não usar duas vezes na mesma expressão uma variável que você está incrementando ou decrementando.
- Se gostaria muito de usar `--n` para resolver o fatorial, execute o código abaixo:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  unsigned int fatqua(unsigned int n){
      printf("\nnumero : %d", n);
      if (n < 2)
          return 1;
      return fatqua(--n) * (n+1);
  }
  void main() {
      unsigned int n, resul = 0;
      printf("Digite um numero: ");
      scanf("%d", &n);
      resul = fatqua(n);
      printf("\n\n Fatorial de %d eh igual a: %d\n", n, resul);
  }
  ```

Note que fica horrível e muito **menos legível** que a primeira forma (com `(n-1)` no parâmetro da chamada recursiva). Além disso, um detalhe seria utilizar `unsigned int` também, já que não existe fatorial de número negativo. Ressalto mais uma vez, pelas razões citadas, que você deve utilizar

```
return n * fatqua(n-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Como já comentado, provavelmente a intenção original seria chamar como parâmetro **--n**. De qualquer modo, isso é perigoso e estraga a operação, pois pela [ordem de precedência de operadores em C](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/apend/precedence.html), o decremento é feito antes da multiplicação propriamente dita, gerando uma recursão da forma

```
n-1 * n-2 * ... * 2 * 1 * 0 * 1
```

Onde cada termo é -1 do que deveria ser (observe que o último *1* é o caso base da recursão, explicitado em *return 1*).

Numa nota extra, seria ainda mais perigoso ainda fazer algo do tipo *fatqua(**n--**)*, pois nesse caso a chamada recursiva ocorre antes do decremento de n. Isso geraria infinitas recursões e, consequentemente, estouro de pilha.